# Proving that if a group is the product of two subgroups, then it is also the product of any conjugates of the subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

I'm working on the following problem:

> Let $A$ and $B$ be subgroups of a group $G$, for which $G=AB$. Further, let $g,h\in G$ be arbitrary.
>
> 1. **Show that $(A^g)(B^h)=G$.**
> 2. **Additionally, show that there is an element $k\in G$ so that $A^g=A^k$ and $B^h=B^k$.**
>
> (To clarify, the notation $A^g$ means $\{g^{-1}ag:a\in A\}$.)

I believe I can prove Part 1:

> **Proof.** Let $g,h\in G$ be given. Clearly $AB=BA$. Express $g=a_1b_1$ and $h=b_2a_2$ with $a_1,a_2\in A$ and $b_1,b_2\in B$. Then $A^gB^h=A^{b_1}B^{a_2}$. Rewrite $b_1a_2^{-1}$ as $a_3b_3$ with $a_3\in A,b_3\in B$. Then,
>
> \begin{align*}
> A^{b_1}B^{a_2}&=b_1^{-1}A(a_3b_3)Ba_2\\
> &=b_1^{-1}ABa_2\\
> &=G.\qquad\blacksquare
> \end{align*}

The problem I'm having is, I don't know how to show that there is a $k\in G$ for which $A^g=A^k$ and $B^h=B^k$. I've tried defining $k$ as a few combinations of $g$ and $h$, but didn't get anywhere.

Most likely, I feel like I'll need to use the fact that $G=AB$ somewhere. I know also that conjugacy can be used as an equivalence relation, although I'm not sure if that will be relevant to this problem or not. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A^gB^h=G \Rightarrow A B^{hg^{-1}} = G$.

Since $G=AB=BA$ we can write $hg^{-1}=ba$ with $a \in A$, $b \in B$.

Let $k=ag$. Then $A^k = A^g$, and $B^k = B^{ag} = B^{bag} = B^h$.

Comment: Amazing, thank you for your beautiful solution! Can I ask how you came up with it? Now it's clear to me that $A^gB^h=G\implies AB^{hg^{-1}}=G$ if I expand using the definition of conjugate, but I would never have realized this fact naturally. In your experience, would you say that it's well-known or "obvious" that $A^gB^h$ may be rewritten as $AB^{hg^{-1}}$ in such a scenario?

Comment: One approach is to try for a solution with more restricted conditions, e.g. when either $g=1$ or $h=1$. Then, in certain situations - as e.g. now - we might be able to reduce the general case to the more specific one.

Comment: I did exactly what Berci suggested and first reduced to the case when $g=1$ by replacing $h$ by $hg^{-1}$. Then it wasn't so hard - as you said yourself, we need to use $G=AB=BA$ somewhere.